# Pandas Multiindex - Select from List

Tags: pandas

I have the following DataFrame with **Index Date and ID**

```
                  V1   V2
Date       ID
01.01.2010  1      x    y
01.01.2010  2      x    y
02.01.2010  1      x    y
        ......
```

I was able to select a date range with

```
df.loc[ slice(start, end) ]
```

But I need to filter data based on a list of ID's. For example

```
allowed = [1, 5]
df.loc[ allowed ]
```

How this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) to check for membership across Index axis. In the case of a multi-index, supply the position of the level or level name explicitly for which the check has to be performed.

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(allowed, level='ID')]    # level name is specified
```

(Or)

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(allowed, level=1)]       # level position is specified
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
In [62]: df
Out[62]:
              V1 V2
Date       ID
2010-01-01 1   x  y
           2   x  y
2010-02-01 1   x  y

In [63]: allowed = [1, 5]

In [64]: df.query("ID in @allowed")
Out[64]:
              V1 V2
Date       ID
2010-01-01 1   x  y
2010-02-01 1   x  y
```